# I'm getting confused with sending data from Jquery to php and retrieve data from it

Tags: jquery, json, post

Here is my HTML code

```
<form action="http://localhost/xiuno" method="post">
    <h1>TEST</h1><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.post("test12.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
        return false;       
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['name'];
echo $a;
```

1.Firstly,when I click submit,it doesn't retrieve any data and redirect to page the form action configed,the return false didn't work.

2.Secondly,even if I remove the form action to this

```
<form method="post">
```

It still didn't retrieve anything from the php script.

3.Lastly,what confused me most is , I'm not sure the data field I'm passing to php

```
{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }
```

is as an object type or json type,I know it would be json if the key was enclosed by quotas like this

```
{ "name": "John", "time": "2pm" }
```

4.Does it mean if I send data like that,there was no need to stringify it cause it is already as of json type?

Comment: Does the console show up a syntax or other error (Are you sure you loaded jquery)? `JSON` is a representation of data like `xml`. For javascript  writing `{ "name": "John", "time": "2pm" }` or `{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }` is nearly the same, except that with using the quotes you can use use keys that you cannot use if you don't use quotes e.g. `{"name 2":"test"}`. So to `4.` no it is not in `json` type but jQuery does the necessary steps for encoding.

Comment: use jquery.ajax i think that's better so exchange data between php and javascript

Comment: @softsdev `post`, `get`, `ajax` and `getJSON` use the same code internally with different default options, so there is no difference, using `jQuery.post` or `jQuery.ajax` with post option.

Comment: No syntax shown there and to verify the Jquery is loaded I simply use the hide() function to test that submit,turns out Jquery is loaded.

Comment: @t.niese Does that mean if I send data using either { "name": "John", "time": "2pm" } or { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ,php script should use json_decode() to use it because it is converted to json before it was passing to php script?I want to test it but the script still not work

Comment: Both are js objects which are converted by jquery into `key` =>  `value` pairs. For `get` it is like writing `?name=John&time=2pm` in the url, so in php you have it (no matter if you use get or post) in your `$_GET`/`$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` with this `key` => `value` pairs. If you would do `{ someKey : '{ "name": "John", "time": "2pm" }'}` you would send a string that has json formatted data. This data you would need to decode with `json_decode($_REQUEST['someKey'])` in your php script.

Comment: @t.niese this code is not working , anything wrong in my code?I'm getting stucking over here.

Comment: @user7031 the code you posted works that way, you can test on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c84BA/ (url is modified to get it working in jsfiddle) so there must a an error shown in the console of your browser.

Comment: @t.niese I finally managed to get it work,by removing the done function and add a call back function inside $.post(url,data,callback);  instead of  $.post(url,data).done();But do not know why?Can you shed some light on it ?

Comment: An too old jQuery version? And i'm pretty sure if you would have looked in console you would have seen a message like `Object has no method 'done'`. You really should learn how to use the developer tools of the browsers.

Comment: @t.niese I'm getting more confused,you said that "So to 4. no it is not in json type but jQuery does the necessary steps for encoding",which means the data was finally send to php script using JSON type,but in the php file I can access the data without using json_decode() function,which probably means that jquery will not automatically convert data to JSON?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32619/discussion-between-t-niese-and-user7031)

Answer (score 0):

Use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) instead of return false and put it in the start.

Comment: using `return false` is `preventDefault` + `stopPropagation` so it should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

**For First**

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("test12.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
        return false;       
    });
});
```

**Second** It will work after removing the `action` from `form element`

**Third** Your both objects have same meaning, because `name` and `time` are keys so, no matters of `single or double quotes`

Comment: As long as there is no error thrown while the `click`callback is executes it makes not difference for this code if you have `preventDefault` at the beginning or not.

Comment: This code didn't work either,it acted the same way my code did.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("form").submit(function() {
       $.post("test12.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });      
return false;   
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This will submit the form the default way if an `action=` is defined there. Because you neither have a `return false` there nor a `preventDefault` on the event.